# Site Template MIA

Tags: 2007

I have uploaded an external template (.stp) to the site templates folder in the Galleries section, but when I go to create a site it isn't showing up anywhere.  Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the site template you have acquired was made using a site definition that you do not currently have.

where did you get the site template? Does it state if you need a particular site definition deployed?

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this before and here is what my observation was.  I saw a template in a gallery(lets just call it templateABC)  However TemplateABC was not appearing under the custom tab on the site provisioning page.  I isolated the issue to the fact that the definition that this template was based off was removed from the farm.  This obviously was the issue.  I was able to determine this by opening up the stp as a cab file and exploring the file a bit.  In my case the definition was pointing to a fab 40 that was uninstalled.  I want to say it was the Helpdesk template.